# Getting proper data in modal

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to access data two times in my template, once on a list view, and once in a modal view. Upon clicking on the image, the modal will display a lot of the same data, just blown up. I'm having issues. The modal seems to be taking the last set of data, even though it's nested in the each statement. Any ideas? Here's my code...

```
<div class="row">
  {{#each model.products as |product|}}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="shopify-grid-wrapper">
        <div id="#image-wrapper" class="image-wrapper" {{action 'openModal'}}>
          <div class="img-overlay">
            <p>
              Click for More Details
            </p>
          </div>
          {{#each product.images as |image|}}
            <img src= {{image.src}} />
          {{/each}}
        </div>
        <div class="description-wrapper">
          <span><p>{{product.title}}</p></span>
          <p>
            {{product.productType}}
          </p>
          <p>
            {{product.tags}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {{#if shopifyModal}}
      {{#liquid-wormhole class="fullscreen-modal" }}
        <div class="left-side">
          {{selectedProduct.title}}
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
          {{buy-button product=product.attrs open="openCart"}}
          <div class="Cart {{if model.isCartOpen "Cart--open"}}">
            {{shopify-cart close="closeCart"}}
          </div>
          <p {{action 'closeModal'}}>
            Close
          </p>
        </div>
      {{/liquid-wormhole}}
    {{/if}}


  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't suppose the missing `div` tag before the `{{#each}}` could be the problem?  (malformed markup)

Comment: Hey @SteveH. I don't see that missing div, care to point it out?

Comment: The line that ends the each (`{{/each}}`) has a close div (`</div>`) on the following line, but it is closing the `div` that starts with the `div` for `#image-wrapper`  Or, you could count the number of start div and end div tags and see if they match up.

Comment: Or another way to point it out:  On line #14, there is a close div (`</div>`).  Where is the opening div that it matches with?

Comment: @SteveH. that </div> closes the opening div with the id of "#image-wrapper". Formatting not ideal here...

Comment: I see.  I've taken the liberty of formatting your code.  Can you clarify what you mean by "taking the last set of data"?  The action doesn't have any parameters, so I assume you have some way to determine which product is being referenced?  Otherwise you may want to pass the product to the action, like `{{action 'openModal' product}}`

Comment: @SteveH. Since the modal is in the loop, one would think that the triggered modal would have the correct data. But whenever the modal opens, it's the last piece of data from the object in the {{#each}} loop.

Comment: @SteveH. Tried passing the product to the action like you mentioned, getting an error...

Comment: FYI: https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/templates/actions/#toc_action-parameters

Comment: thank you @SteveH. that's how it's done!! I was messing it up earlier by not passing 'product' into the action's function.

Comment: Great!  You'll also need to get rid of the ID #image-wrapper. Your code will have many divs with the same id since it’s in the each loop.

Comment: Thanks! Good point, I'll be conscious of keeping my HTML clean when looping.

Comment: RE image-wrapper... _easy way to deal with ID's_ is to just not use them.

Comment: Sounds like this question is answered! : )

Comment: PS - https://github.com/ef4/ember-elsewhere is pretty awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was answered in the comments, but I'm adding this here in case someone finds it.

When looping over a collection in a template, if you have an action inside that loop, you must pass some information to the action handler if you expect the "current" item to be processed by the action handler, like this:

```
{{action 'openModal' product}}
```